# VideoPlayerController not working inside inside Existing Android App

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to integrate with flutter with the existing Android App. Basic page of flutter is working fine. However when try running video using VideoPlayerController it breaks with below error. When I try same code in pure flutter app it works. Any idea how to fix it.

Error
VideoPlayerApi
exception = {PlatformException} PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null)
replyMap = null

```
VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          setState(() {
            _controller.play();
            _controller.setLooping(true);
          });
        });
```

Comment: is there any answer to this question?